# Keep cmd open in c#

Tags: c#, cmd

Is it possible to open a command prompt in c#, and keep the instance around to be reused?

**Edit (thanks to the comments below)**

More generally put, I want to know if it's possible to spawn a process and continually direct input/output to it.

Example: Execute fsi (fsharp interpreter), and using console.readline to forward requests to the current fsi that's running.

Comment: Please leave a comment as to why you're down-voting. If I'm doing something wrong I'd like to know so that I won't repeat my mistakes in future questions. Cheers.

Comment: I didn't down vote, and I think I get your question from the example, but it could possibly be worded better. I think what you actually mean is you want to spawn a process and continually direct input/output to it.

Comment: I guess, you don't want us to write the code for you. Then What is your question specifically (otherwise I can only say: *Yes it is possible*)

Comment: @ameer yeah my bad. I think the issue is that I had an idea in my head already so I didn't extract the essence of the question very well.

Comment: @I4V really I just wanted to know if it was possible and possibly links or an example to point me in the right direction. I think ameer was correct in that my question wasn't stated as clearly as it could've been.

Comment: @JesseBuesking `links or an example to point me in the right direction`, you should know the closing reason: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam*

Answer (score 1):

You can spawn the process and redirect input/output to the process using process's [StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx) / [StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) properties. I think the MSDN examples on those links will help you do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!

Create an instance of the System.Diagnostics.Process class, then redirect the required streams.
This allows you to easily control any cmd-line process and/or the cmd itself. Read the class information in the MSDN library for sync and async options and useful properties, methods, and events.

Hope that helps...